# setting mysql resource limit for individual person

Tags: php, mysql

```
$dsn="mysql:host=localhost; dbname=account";
$username="member";...
```

I have a sit, use PDO connect to mysql.

I try to set up MySQL Resource limits, if i set up username-member and set limit query 5000 per hour, is this mean everyone log on my site will not be able to query after it hit the limit? How can I set up per person?

ex. if 'foo' log on and he have his session, how can i set up the limit only for foo?

Comment: You could store the number of queries each user has used in the database. When they log in, check this value. If it is above the limit, do not execute the query.

Comment: Are you referring to MySQL user credentials, or application user credentials?